# gradle dsl method not found 'compile()' Error:(10,0)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gson, retrofit, build.gradle

I want to use Gson and Retrofit to interact with an API. According to the documentations, I add theses lines into the build.gradle of my project:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral() //this line
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7' //this line
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0' //this line
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral() //and this line
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

but I have these errors :

> Error:(10, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()' Possible
>   causes:
>
> The project 'TempoEDF' may be using a version of the
>   Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g.
>   'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0). Upgrade
>   plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project
>
> The project
>   'TempoEDF' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the
>   method. Open Gradle wrapper
>   file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

So I used the Gradle plugin like my IDE wants to:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    apply plugin: 'gradle'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

but I have this error :

> Error:(10, 0) Plugin with id 'gradle' not found. Open
>   File

What did I do wrong?

Comment: add these lines to app level gradle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so according to the documentations i add theses lines into the build.gradle of my project

Please note the comments in that file:

```
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
```

I do not know what "documentations" that you read that told you to put these things in the project-level `build.gradle` file. Please consider providing links, so that we can get that material fixed.

To get past this problem, remove the changes that you made to this file. Then, add those dependencies to the *module's* `build.gradle` file (e.g., `app/build.gradle` in a typical Android Studio project).